# Download local files off of a website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to inspect the contents of this file (or download it and somehow search that way) named "(index)" (it doesn't have any extension if that matters) on my target website (reddit.com) to search through and find an access token to then use later in my script.

How would I go about doing this? Also, this seems like a roundabout way of doing it, so do you have any suggestions that would be better? For example, is there a command I can execute in the console with driver.execute_script("something") to then search the file for me?

I have tried driver.page_source, but, as expected it doesn't return anything involving the pages files.

Comment: you're asking how to get the access token? often in http headers, instead of page source.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not getting the part I need from the responses (There are two parts to it. One part I can get, but the other part is this weird encoded timestamp: SO831eY9LsWKcmf-srHS6QX20fcl-A). If I can, I would much rather build up this timestamp, but I can't figure out how to decode it.

Comment: using selenium is simulating human operations, and as human do you care about tokens? you just enter user and password whenever necessary.

Comment: I'm trying to do a mixture of selenium and requests. Im going to use selenium to grab this token, then later use that token in the requests section of my script. (I need it for the authorization header)